# inner join of one table and prevent duplicate?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called

trade with the following column (removed alot of redundant data)

trade_id,buyer_company_code, seller_company_code, legacy_trade_number.

I intent to query all trade where there  one trade's buyer_company_code = another trade's seller_company_code and the trade's seller_company_code = another buyer   buyer_company code

I tried with the query that result in the screenshot below

```
select * from trade tradetable1 inner join trade tradetable2
 on tradetable1.seller_company_code=tradetable2.buyer_company_code and tradetable1.buyer_company_code=tradetable2.seller_company_code
    and tradetable1.legacy_trade_number<tradetable2.legacy_trade_number
```

[image]

It currently gives me the following (legacy_trade_number from one trade) and (legacy_trade_numbe from another trade) with duplicates (due to cartesian product)

5548  5554 
5548  5555
5548  5556
5549  5554
5549  5555 
5549  5556 
5550  5554 
5550  5555 
5550  5556

but i requires it to be as follows

5548  5554 
5549  5555
5550  5556

Where the two column have no duplicate value. Any suggestion/hint will be helpful! thanks

Comment: Your current sample result shows `5554`, `5555`, and `5556` in the second column next to `5548` in the first. It looks like you only want to see the lowest of those three second-column values. Is that correct? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: i wanted the two column combination to be unique with only one appearing on each side, without duplicate. Was wondering if this could be sql doable. I know i can easily use my query result i got above and filter them in my application code

Comment: It is doable of course. But you have not yet specified the problem well enough to solve in SQL.  The problem is, several trade numbers in tradetable1 match the criterion `tradetable1.legacy_trade_number<tradetable2.legacy_trade_number` in your ON condition.  Which of those several do you want to display? The least one?  When working with SQL, you are describing *sets* of values.

Answer (score 3):

if you don't want duplicated  result for the column legacy_trade_number  then instead  of select * you should select only the columns you really need

```
select distinct tradetable1.legacy_trade_number from (
    select * from trade 
) tradetable1 
inner join ( 
select * 
from trade ) tradetable2 on tradetable1.seller_company_code=tradetable2.buyer_company_code 
    and tradetable1.buyer_company_code=tradetable2.seller_company_code
    and tradetable1.legacy_trade_number<tradetable2.legacy_trade_number
```

any way the result could be obtained  simple using

```
select disticnt t1.legacy_trade_number 
from  trade  t1 
inner join trade t2 on on t1.seller_company_code=t2.buyer_company_code 
    and t1.buyer_company_code=t2.seller_company_code
    and t1.legacy_trade_number<t2.legacy_trade_number
```

The duplication in evaluated  at row level so  ..  if you need  others column you should choose which value you want  and use aggreagtion function for reduce the unuseful values

eg: using an aggregation function as min()  you could

```
select t1.legacy_trade_number, min(t1.col1), min(t2.coln)
from  trade  t1 
inner join trade t2 on on t1.seller_company_code=t2.buyer_company_code 
    and t1.buyer_company_code=t2.seller_company_code
    and t1.legacy_trade_number<t2.legacy_trade_number
  group by t1.legacy_trade_number
```

Comment: thanks !  

However, this approach result in only one column being shown
 18/N00548
18/N00549
18/N00550

Comment: added  a sample for aggreagted  result too.

Comment: yes i understood this, but there is nothing to aggregate it against. If i have miss out something, please do advice!.  The end goal is to get the final two  column in my question above.

Comment: the result you want  is not based on a relational approach  .. which is the logic  .. for the result  ..  ??  .